# NEO4J Server startup issue java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: neo4j

The neo4j server is not able to start and i am getting an error `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException`

I have added the complete trace below:

```
2017-04-17 06:31:12.832+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@40e621fd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@40e621fd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@40e621fd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:227)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@40e621fd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:443)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:199)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:193)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:57)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@26a34b49' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:415)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:517)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:189)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.readDynamicRecord(PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.java:492)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.readDynamicRecords(PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.java:506)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.readPropertyRecord(PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.java:564)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.visitPropertyCommand(PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.java:189)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.read(PhysicalLogCommandReaderV3_0_2.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.BaseCommandReader.read(BaseCommandReader.java:49)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.BaseCommandReader.read(BaseCommandReader.java:34)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryParsersV2_3$3.parse(LogEntryParsersV2_3.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader.readLogEntry(VersionAwareLogEntryReader.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogEntryCursor.next(LogEntryCursor.java:54)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.LatestCheckPointFinder.find(LatestCheckPointFinder.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.PositionToRecoverFrom.apply(PositionToRecoverFrom.java:53)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI.getPositionToRecoverFrom(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:405)
```

Comment: The Path to your database files is not set right.

Comment: i am also facing same issue

Comment: It was working correctly , suddenly after a crash it started showing this message for me @DenisKohl

Comment: The path to the database is correct /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db

Comment: try reinstalling java 8

Comment: I got this one after full disk and application restart